# Adding javascript variables together

Tags: javascript, addition

Can anyone help me with why this does not work like Im expecting.
What im trying to do is add to a javascript variable based on drop downs.

So:
Question 1
If yes x=x+1

Question 2
If yes x=x+3

so if yes to both x=4

Right now, this will not let x add to x, instead, it reasigns x every time

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
var z=1
var y=1
</script>
<script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#checkbox_1").change(function () { 
                if($(this).val() == "Yes") {
                    var x=y;
                    $("#textbox_1").attr('disabled', true);
                    $("#textbox_1").val(x);
                    }
                    else {
                    var x=x-1;
                    $("#textbox_1").attr('disabled', true);
                    $("#textbox_1").val(0);
                    }
                });
            });
</script>   
<script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#checkbox_2").change(function () { 
                if($(this).val() == "Yes") {
                    var x=y+z;
                    $("#textbox_1").attr('disabled', true);
                    $("#textbox_1").val(x);
                    }
                    else {
                    var x=x-1;
                    $("#textbox_1").attr('disabled', true);
                    $("#textbox_1").val(0);
                    }
                });
            });
</script>    

Do you have your Vheicals Title?<br />
<SELECT class="enteredClassic" id="checkbox_1"/>
<OPTION selected value=No>Select Option</OPTION>
<OPTION value=No>No</OPTION>
<OPTION value=Yes>Yes</OPTION>
</SELECT>
<br />
<br />
Do you earn more then $1,500 per month?<br />
<SELECT class="enteredClassic" id="checkbox_2" />
<OPTION selected value=No>Select Option</OPTION>
<OPTION value=No>No</OPTION>
<OPTION value=Yes>Yes</OPTION>
</SELECT>
<br />
<br />
Your chances of funding: <br />
<SELECT class="enteredYear" id="textbox_1" name=year>
            <OPTION selected value="0">0%</OPTION>
            <OPTION value=1>10%</OPTION>
            <OPTION value=2>20%</OPTION>
            <OPTION value=3>30%</OPTION>
            </SELECT>
```

Comment: `x` should be a global variable like y and z. They do not share scope between the two checkbox polls.

Comment: Also, your HTML markup is horrible. ALL property values should have quotation marks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cleaned up your script...

```
<script>
           $(document).ready(function () {
                var x = 0;
                $("#checkbox_1").change(function () { 
                if($(this).val() == "Yes") {
                    x++;
                    $("#textbox_1").prop('disabled', true);
                    $("#textbox_1").val(x);
                    }
                    else {
                    x--;
                    $("#textbox_1").prop('disabled', false);
                    $("#textbox_1").val(x); // I don't understand why this is 0
                    }
                });
                $("#checkbox_2").change(function () { 
                if($(this).val() == "Yes") {
                    x += 3;
                    $("#textbox_1").prop('disabled', true);
                    $("#textbox_1").val(x);
                    }
                    else {
                    x -= 3;
                    $("#textbox_1").prop('disabled', false);
                    $("#textbox_1").val(x); // or this one. shouldn't it be x?
                    }
                });
            });
</script>
```

Edited to reflect more acceptable usage of `.prop` rather than `.attr`.

Comment: Not only did you clean it up, but you showed me what I was doing wrong also!! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

[Link to jsbin](http://jsbin.com/egonut/3/edit)

**Markup**

```
<label>
  Do you have your Vheicals Title?
  <select class="enteredClassic" id="title">
    <option selected value="No">select option</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
  </select>
</label>

<label>
  Do you earn more then $1,500 per month?
  <select class="enteredClassic" id="income">
    <option selected value=No>select option</option>
    <option value=No>No</option>
    <option value=Yes>Yes</option>
  </select>
</label>

<label>
  Your chances of funding:
  <select class="enteredYear" id="chances" name=year>
    <option selected value="0">0%</option>
    <option value="1">10%</option>
    <option value="3">30%</option>
    <option value="4">40%</option>
  </select>
</label>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".enteredClassic").change(function () {
    var chances = 0;
    if($("#title").val() == 'Yes') chances++;
    if($("#income").val() == 'Yes') chances += 3;
    $("#chances").val(chances);
  });
});
```

**CSS**

```
select { 
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should declare x globally similar to how you declare y and z. You cannot use a variable you never declared which is what you are essentially doing.

```
var x = x - 1; //uses the variable x which has not been created yet
```

Instead of var'ing x inside the function var it where y and z are. But I might not understand what your code is trying to achieve.